# database for android application

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite

I am trying to create application that reads users (name,position,and their blood group). I will put these info in database to be able to achieve them when I need.
do I have to use (Sqlite database) or (Sql server database)?

Comment: "*do I have to use (Sqlite database) or (Sql server database)*" - it is completely up to you and depends on your requirements. In any case, you can't use sql server database directly on your android device, so it should be at some external service if you prefer to use it.

Comment: i want all users to be able to read and write from the same database. so  if i used sqlite, can i allow others to read and write shared info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's depend on your requirement but if you want stored data locally use sqlite and if you want store data on server use sqlServer
for sqlite : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

for SqlServer you can not connect directly,you should use an script on your server and call it from application, or use [jtds](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i want all users to be able to read and write from the same database. so  if i used sqlite, can i allow others to read and write shared info?

Comment: @Saleh923 in the same device yes u can but for shared database along more than one device, u should use external database like SQLServer